# how to iterate over all keys in dictionary python?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, machine-learning

I am supposed to count the frequency of all the key values of dictionary "d" across all the files in the document "individual-articles' Here,the document "individual-articles' has around 20000 txt files,with filenames 1,2,3,4... for ex: suppose d[Britain]=[5,76,289] must return the number of times Britain appears in the files 5.txt,76.txt,289.txt belonging to the document "induvidual articles", and also i need to find its frequency across all the files in the same document.

```
import collections
import sys
import os
import re
sys.stdout=open('dictionary.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob


folderpath='d:/individual-articles'
counter=Counter()


filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))

def words_generator(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word
word_count_dict = {}
for file in filepaths:
    f = open(file,"r")
    words = words_generator(f)
    for word in words:
        if word not in word_count_dict:
              word_count_dict[word] = {"total":0}
        if file not in word_count_dict[word]:
              word_count_dict[word][file] = 0
        word_count_dict[word][file] += 1              
        word_count_dict[word]["total"] += 1        
for k in word_count_dict.keys():
    for filename in word_count_dict[k]:
        if filename == 'total': continue
        counter.update(filename)

for k in word_count_dict.keys():
    for count in counter.most_common():
        print('{}  {}'.format(word_count_dict[k],count))
```

how do i find the frequency of britain only in those files which are elements of the dictionary for that key value?

i need to store these values in another d2 for the same example, d2 must contain

(Britain,26,1200)
 (Spain,52,6795)
 (France,45,568)

where 26 is the frequency of the word Britain in the files 5.txt,76.txt and 289.txt and 1200 is the frequency of the word Britain in all the files. 
Similarly for spain and france.

I am using counter here, and i think that is the defect because,so far everything works fine, except for my final loop!

I am a python newbie, and i have tried little! please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word_count_dict["Britain"]` is a regular dictionary. Just loop over it:

```
for filename in word_count_dict["Britain"]:
    if filename == 'total': continue
    print("Britain appears in {} {} times".format(filename, word_count_dict["Britain"][filename]))
```

or retrieve all the keys with:

```
word_count_dict["Britain"].keys()
```

Do note that you have one special key `total` in that dictionary.

It may be that your indentation is off, but it appears you are not correctly counting your file entries:

```
if file not in word_count_dict[word]:
    word_count_dict[word][file] = 0
    word_count_dict[word][file] += 1              
    word_count_dict[word]["total"] += 1
```

would only count (`+= 1`) words if `file` had not been seen in the per-word dictionary before; correct that to:

```
if file not in word_count_dict[word]:
    word_count_dict[word][file] = 0
word_count_dict[word][file] += 1              
word_count_dict[word]["total"] += 1
```

To expand this to arbitrary words, you loop over the outer `word_count_dict`:

```
for word, counts in word_count_dict.iteritems():
    print('Total counts for word {}: '.format(word, counts['total']))
    for filename, count in counts.iteritems():
        if filename == 'total': continue
        print("{} appears in {} {} times".format(word, filename, count))
```

Comment: and suppose i have multiple words like, "britain","france","spain",and so will this work: for k in word_count_dict.keys():

Comment: @radhika: exactly. There `k` is itself a dictionary mapping filenames to counts.

Comment: so will this be correct? for k in word_count_dict.keys():    for filename in word_count_dict[k]:
    if filename == 'total': continue
    print(k+" appears in {} {} times".format(filename, word_count_dict[k][filename]))

Comment: @radhika: I'd say so, yes. :-)

Comment: i have edited the question, could you please look into the final loop?thanks in advance

Comment: @radhika: You got confused between words and filenames. The outer dictionary keys are words. The values of that dictionary are *other* dictionaries, whose keys are filenames and values are counts.

Comment: i don't want this line print("{} appears in {} {} times".format(word, filename, count)) to be printed, instead i want the total,so, i know that print(sum(count)) won't work,any other alternative that you could suggest?

Comment: @radhika: The total of what? All words? Total count for that word? Total words in a file? You *already* have `count['total']` for the total count of that word.

Comment: no, the total no. of counts for each word,here say for "britain", the no. of times it appears in file1 is 2,file2 is 5 and file3 is 1,then i require 8(5+2+1) to be printed. this must be done for all the words.

Comment: @radhika: Yes, that is what your `total` key gives you. `print('Total counts for word {}: '.format(word, counts['total']))` prints that count.